# IBM Cloud: Error trying to create Code Engine project

Tags: ibm-cloud, knative, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I am trying to create a new [IBM Cloud Code Engine](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/knative) project on the command line, but am running into errors.

```
$ ibmcloud coligo proj create -n HLTest

Creating project 'HLTest'...
FAILED
Cannot target project HLTest
```

Listing my projects with `ibmcloud coligo proj list` succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tracing the command using `IBMCLOUD_TRACE=true` I found an error indicating that my currently set cloud region is not enabled. Setting `ibmcloud target -r us-south` and then executing the above `ibmcloud coligo proj create -n HLTest` succeeded.

Lessons learned: Listing projects is global, creating a project only works when a supported cloud region has been targeted before.

From @vidya's answer: Also set the resource group using `ibmcloud target -g RG` with RG being the resource group. Each account has a default resource group.

Answer (score 1):

Another best practice is to set the resource group before creating a Code Engine project with the command below

`ibmcloud target -g Default`

`Default` is the default resource group automatically created when you create an IBM Cloud account